# How to plot important features from a trained Support Vector Machine/LinearSVC?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis

Code ends like this - how can i plot the features and the importance of them, if there's a way to do that automatically.
similar to this

```
    ....

    classifier_liblinear = svm.LinearSVC(loss='squared_hinge',max_iter=1000)
    classifier_liblinear.fit(train_vectors, train_labels)
```

(from http://mlwave.com/movie-review-sentiment-analysis-with-vowpal-wabbit/)
[image]

Comment: I figured it out - at least to get a report

`import numpy as np  

def show_most_informative_features(vectorizer, clf, n=20):  
    feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()  
    coefs_with_fns = sorted(zip(clf.coef_[0], feature_names))  
    top = zip(coefs_with_fns[:n], coefs_with_fns[:-(n + 1):-1])  
    for (coef_1, fn_1), (coef_2, fn_2) in top:  
        print "\t%.4f\t%-15s\t\t%.4f\t%-15s" % (coef_1, fn_1, coef_2, fn_2)  
  
show_most_informative_features(vectorizer, classifier_liblinear, 75)  `